# Spring Boot ActiveMQ AWS deployment issue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, activemq-classic, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring Boot App that uses ActiveMQ to enqueue mail messages (POJO class). The queue is deployed in the cloud (a separate node) under an ec2 instance of amazon located at: **tcp://public_ip:61616**. When I run the .jar locally my application works without any problem; mail messages are queued and dequeued.

The problem appears when I upload the same .jar to AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java Platform. When the .jar is executed from the cloud (previously executed locally) the messages go to the "ActiveMQ.DLQ" queue. The messages are queued but not dequeued. My question is why my Spring Boot app when deployed in the cloud is not dequeuing messages?

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>xxxxxxProject</name>
    <description>xxxxx</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JMS -->
        <dependency>              
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>           
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>         
        </dependency>         
        <dependency>              
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>            
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>          
        </dependency>         
        <dependency>              
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>             
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>         
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Mail -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Json Web Token-->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vladmihalcea/hibernate-types-5 -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-types-5</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-hibernate5 -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.133</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>    
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

My App.Properties File:

```
#SpringFrameworkVersion: 4.3.13.RELEASE
#SSL Properties:
server.port=8083
server.use-forward-headers=true
#server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
#DataBase Properties:
app.db.user=xxx
app.db.password=xxx
app.db.host=xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
#app.db.host=localhost
app.db.port=3306
app.db.scheme=xxxxxkBD
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://public_ip:61616?jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=1
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_empty
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true
amazonS3Properties.endpointUrlBase=https://s3.amazonaws.com
amazonS3Properties.bucketName=zzzzz.com
amazonS3Properties.region=us-east-1
#Recordar que faltan las propiedades de llave para conectarse a AWS S3
amazonS3Properties.accessKey=xx
amazonS3Properties.secretKey=xx
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=4MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

My Configuration Spring Boot Bean:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JavaMessageServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean         
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory( ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {            
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        return factory;   
    }

    // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
```

My Producer Class:

```
@Component
public class Mail implements ApplicationListener<GenericEvent>{

    @Autowired 
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(GenericEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof UserRegistrationEvent) {
            UserRegistrationEvent registrationEvent = (UserRegistrationEvent) event;
            createUserRegistrationEmailMessage(registrationEvent.getId(), registrationEvent.getEmail(),
                    registrationEvent.getName(), registrationEvent.getAppUrl());
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    private void createUserRegistrationEmailMessage(int id, String to, String name, String appUrl) {
        EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(env.getProperty("support.email"), to, subject, body.toString());
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("mailbox",emailMessage);
    }
}
```

My consumer class:

```
@Component
public class MailSender {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Async
    @JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
    public void sendEmail(EmailMessage emailMessage) throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("Dequeue e-mail");
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        helper.setFrom(emailMessage.getFrom());
        helper.setTo(emailMessage.getTo());
        helper.setSubject(emailMessage.getSubject());
        helper.setText(emailMessage.getBody(), true);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Keep in mind the logic of behavior so they can have a better idea of what happens:

When I run the .jar locally, the application works without problems. Now, I stop the .jar locally, next I do the AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment of this same .jar, but messages are going to the "ActiveMQ.DLQ".

[image]

Then, if I run the .jar locally again, the application stops working (The messages are going to the "ActiveMQ.DLQ", with the same cause shown in the image).

To get it to work again locally, I have to run the local .jar and simultaneously redeploy this same .jar on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In this way the local .jar begins to dequeue the messages again without problems. Apparently, when deploying, the connection to the queue is restarted and the connection to the local .jar works again. It's a strangest behavior that I still can't understand

Comment: To clarify, when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk your application is able to access the EC2 node running ActiveMQ and enqueue messages? If things are working fine locally then I'm thinking that it's not your code that is the issue but the security groups or networking policies applied to the EC2 instance that your application is running in (Elastic Beanstalk runs your application in an EC2 instance).

Comment: @Simon "when deploying to Elastic Beanstalk your application is able to access the EC2 node running ActiveMQ and enqueue messages?" Yes. All ec2 instances have the rule of allowing all types of traffic. The strange thing is that it deploys without errors, the only thing that is not done in the cloud is to decouple the messages .... The messages arrive at the queue

Comment: Seems @Simon got a point. If your Beanstalk application not runs on `default-subnet`, check subnet configuration as well. Deployment may not give you an error, but network level access still can be a problem.

Comment: @SachithDickwella Thank you for your contribution. But I don't understand why I should check subnet configuration, if the node where the queue is deployed has a public ip, if the .jar locally uses the remote queue, in the same way the .jar in the cloud accesses the queue. The problem is that the messages are not dequeue. Because I check the activemq administration console and the messages if they are enqueue.

Comment: FWIW, messages typically get put on a DLQ when an application attempts to consume the messages and fails (e.g. the app gets the message but fails to process it properly). Perhaps something is failing when the consumer tries to send the email which is causing rollbacks for the JMS message consumption. You've set `jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=1` on your URL so redelivery will only be attempted once before the message goes to the DLQ.

Comment: @JustinBertram I have tried to send it infinitely with parameter -1 "jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=-1", but it does not work, I enter the administration console of activemq and I see the message enqueued, but it does not disengage

Comment: @AlejoDev, Ok. Let me get this straight. Your locally running `.jar` can access (`enqueue`/`dequeue`) the remote ActiveMQ broker that deployed in a EC2 instance, publicly exposed via `61616` port through an Elastic IP. But if you deploy the same `.jar` (in different EC2 instance) without making any change to the broker's deployment, it only `enqueue` the message, do not `dequeue`. Is that right?  Does your application throw any exception?

Comment: @SachithDickwella Quite so! the application does not generate some kind of exception, all the flow is given, as the queue is asynchronous, the flow occurs without problems. The only thing is that the consumer never dequeue the message. When I check the queue from the administration console, I check the DLQ queue and the error cause is "DeliveryFailureCause = Exceeded redeliveryPolicy"

Comment: I don't think changing `jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries` to `-1` will help. It seems to me that the consumer is actually getting the message but it's failing for some reason which causes the redeliveryPolicy to be exceeded which sends the message to the DLQ. Changing `maximumRedeliveries` to `-1` just means that delivery will be attempted indefinitely and the message will never be sent to the DLQ. You need to find the root cause of the failure.

Comment: @JustinBertram Check the update in the question